# If I catch a legendary and I release it, then I beat Elite Four, can I find that Pokemon again?

Tags: pokemon-omega-ruby-alpha-sapphire

In Pokemon ORAS, I want to SR for shiny legionaries, but I already caught almost all of them, and I wanna be able to SR for them, so my question is, if I release all the legendary Pokemon I have, and then beat the elite four again, do they re-appear?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Once you catch a legendary Pokemon it will not re-appear, even if you release it. They only re-appear after defeating the Elite Four if you caused them to faint rather than catch.

While not an ideal solution, you could deposit *all* your Pokemon into the Pokebank app (if you've already used your free trial period, you will need to pay for access which is ~$5 for a year), and then restart the game. As long as you are on the same system/Nintendo Network ID you should be able to withdraw all your old Pokemon from the bank onto your new save. This does mean you would need to re-complete the entire story again - but you have another shot at catching all the legendaries and soft resetting for shinies.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't. They re-appear only of you defeat them.